# Amadeus .Net Sdk shows 401 error for shopping.flightOffers.get function though other function works

Tags: .net, api, sdk, amadeus

I am trynig .Net Sdk for amadeus self service api integration from https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-dotnet.

I have tested some endpoints succesfully but failed to get result for low price flight search api.

From their documentation bellow coe should work but it shows 401 error.

```
// Flight Low-fare Search
FlightOffer[] flightOffers = amadeus.shopping.flightOffers.get(Params
  .with("origin", "NYC")
  .and("destination", "MAD")
  .and("departureDate", "2021-05-01"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to change versions of API from V1 to V2. Change the URL on the FlightOffers class to: /v2/shopping/flight-offers
In addition the parameters name also changed: originLocationCode, destinationLocationCode.

```
amadeus.resources.FlightOffer[] flightOffer = amadeus.shopping.flightOffers.get(Params
            .with("originLocationCode", "LHR")
            .and("destinationLocationCode", "LAX")
            .and("departureDate", "2021-12-24")
            .and("adults", "1"));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. What about i use nuget package 'Afonsoft.Amadeus' which uses version 2 api but shows that authentication error?